# Retrieving authentication status and current user with ng-token-auth

Tags: angularjs, authentication

I'm using [ng-token-auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/ng-token-auth) along with [devise_token_auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth) in my AngularJS application. I have implemented login and logout successfully, but I'm having trouble doing the following:

1. Determining whether the user is authenticated, and
2. retrieving the current user's info.

I've partially solved 1 by using event subscribers:

```
myApp.run(['$rootScope',
  ($rootScope)->
    $rootScope.isAuthenticated = false

    $rootScope.$on('auth:validation-success', (e)->
      $rootScope.isAuthenticated = true
    )
    $rootScope.$on('auth:login-success', (e)->
      $rootScope.isAuthenticated = true
    )

    $rootScope.$on('auth:validation-error', (e)->
      $rootScope.isAuthenticated = false
    )
    $rootScope.$on('auth:invalid', (e)->
      $rootScope.isAuthenticated = false
    )
    $rootScope.$on('auth:login-error', (e)->
      $rootScope.isAuthenticated = false
    )
    $rootScope.$on('auth:logout-success', (e)->
      $rootScope.isAuthenticated = false
    )
    $rootScope.$on('auth:account-destroy-success', (e)->
      $rootScope.isAuthenticated = false
    )
    $rootScope.$on('auth:session-expired', (e)->
      $rootScope.isAuthenticated = false
    )
])
```

However, I am not sure this is the best way to do it. Maybe I should do it in a
service instead?

Regarding 2, I have installed [angular-resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) and configured a `User` resource, but I'm not really sure where to retrieve the user info (a service? a controller?) and how to update it when the user updates their profile (should I just listen to event subscribers or just reload the info on each state change?).

I'm fairly new to Angular, so please let me know if I'm doing anything else wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would strongly recommend you create some kind of a UserService, which will hold all of your authentication and user data, and all logic functions you have regarding users, as well as using the User resource, for Getting, Creating, Updating, Deleting, Authenticating, Log off, etc...
you should really avoid using the $rootScope here, this is not what its meant for, there are really not a lot of situations you would have like to place data on the $rootScope anyway.

so in the UserService i would recommend you save the user's info,

```
function UserService(User) {
    var _user = null;

    this.getUserFromServer = function(userid) {
         User.get(userId).$promise.then(user) { _user = user;  };
    }

    this.isAuthenticated = fucntion (){ 
        return user !== null;          
    } 

    this.logoff = fucntion (){ 
        user = null;          
    } 
}
```

so this way i solved two of the problems you had, 
use the event listeners you created to trigger the functions above.

good luck.

Comment: How would I access this data from a template?

Comment: add a new function to the UserService - this.getUser = function () { return _user };                             this function can be used inside any controller you and you can attach it to the $scope and use it in a template

Comment: Okay, and how do I subscribe to the events from inside the service?

Comment: you mean the devise events ? you dont have to subscribe to them inside the service, you can keep them where they are in the run function, i even recommend you keep it there, if you must do it you can add the $rootScope the injectables of the UserService and subscribe the events from there.